Is it rude to ask for confirmation/proof of my conjecture?
I have a conjecture (I promise, it is not my homework). Is it rude to ask people to give any light about its validity and the topic?

Don't know "rude", but almost certainly off topic.

It is not rude to ask for proof or disproof of your conjecture. Math.SE is not just for problems already solved, e.g. homework.

Before you post your conjecture, please do the most thorough search you can to see whether anything like it is already out there. Also, try your hardest to refute it.

Well, the fact that there exists a tag, especially created for handling proof verifications, shows me that questions like that might be on topic here: tag URL: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification

@Dominique Well, there's a big gap between "there exists a thing that suggests it" and "you can do it like you want."  Community standards evolve over time, and it would be silly to make ourselves permanently enslaved by decisions of the past.  So, asking in meta, as this user is doing, is probably a prudent first step.

In general, such a question is probably off-topic here (not rude to ask, just not on-topic, and likely to be closed).
The goal of the StackExchange network is designed to create a repository of high quality question-and-answer posts which are likely to be useful for both the original asker of a question, as well as future readers who might have the same question.  Questions which are narrowly focused on the interests of a single person are unlikely to be well-received on the site, as such questions are not likely to be of much use to other readers in the future.
Additionally, Math SE is not designed to do the job of peer review.  If you have a new result, this probably isn't the place to ask for feedback.  If there is a specific part of your argument which you aren't certain about, you might ask about that bit (with the rest of the conjecture providing context for why you are asking about that bit), but a better reviewer might be someone you know in your local math department, or a journal editor.
In addition to the Q&A How to ask a good question, I would suggest that you read the guidance on the solution-verification tag, which should give you some idea how to ask questions about proofs.

Thanks, I see here is not the most suitable place to share new results and ask for help about some path, although is acceptable to ask such questions. Unfortunately I am not part of any departament, I have no affiliation, I am just a hobbyist.

Stated properly, it is neither rude nor off-topic. But: (1) You should formulate this not as a conjecture but as a question. (2) You should follow general guidelines on How to ask a good question.
